# How to fetch a specific iTunesTrack instance from iTunes via the Scripting Bridge using persistenID?

Tags: cocoa, itunes, scripting-bridge

Using the iTunes Scripting Bridge interface, I need to fetch a particular iTunesTrack by its persistentID.  I closely examined the header file produced sdp/sdef but it looks like there is no method in the existing interface for performing any kind of query for a track based on any parameter.  The next idea I had was to enumerate all of the tracks examining each for a match.

The implication is that this would be slow; the larger the target library the worse the performance.  I'm wondering if anyone has a proven solution to this problem that doesn't involve examining every track returned from the scripting bridge, one at a time?

At [get a specific track in itunes via ScriptingBridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766615/get-a-specific-track-in-itunes-via-scriptingbridge), Arr MiHardies states that he came up with a solution and would post it but apparently, he never got around to it.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to get the entire iTunes library as an array, then use Cocoa's `NSPredicate` filtering to find what you want.

```
iTunesApplication *iTunes = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.iTunes"];
SBElementArray *iTunesSources = [iTunes sources];
iTunesSource *library;
for (iTunesSource *thisSource in iTunesSources) {
    if ([thisSource kind] == iTunesESrcLibrary) {
        library = thisSource;
        break;
    }
}
SBElementArray *libraryPlaylists = [library libraryPlaylists];
iTunesLibraryPlaylist *libraryPlaylist = [libraryPlaylists objectAtIndex:0];
SBElementArray *musicTracks = [self.libraryPlaylist fileTracks];    
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"persistentID == %@", persistentID];
[musicTracks filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

In general it's often a good rule of thumb to do as little as possible with Scripting Bridge methods—use them to get the data out, then use normal Cocoa methods for everything else.